# Is there a way to call the windows screenshot snipping tool (win+shift+s) in python?

Tags: python, screenshot

I'm wondering if there's a way to active the windows screenshot snipping tool from a python program. Currently I'm using pynput to press the windows + shift + s key but I feel that there is a better way to perform this.

I've tried to use subprocess to call snipping tool.

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe'])
```

It opens the actual application but it's not the same as the windows+shift+s one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SnippingTool.exe` provides some command line options to control its behavior.
See [How to open the SnippingTool (Win Tool) passing a parameter to start automatically?](https://superuser.com/q/1094137/1095942)

To start taking a screenshot (as <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> does), pass `/clip` as an argument to it like this.

```py
subprocess.call([r'C:\\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe', '/clip'])
```